# Drop event Call on Position fixed Div when div is scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have scenario where a top div(Yellow)color with position fix and which contain draggable children div (Red Border).
The drag and drop is working fine, but if i scroll down in a way that Yellow div overlap to blue div and drag (Red Border) div and drop inside in (Yellow) div then drop event of (Blue Color)div is call.

I dont want to call drop event if i drop div inside (Yellow) div.

Bellow the JS Fiddle http://tinyurl.com/nxoluw8

Comment: Is this ok? http://jsfiddle.net/bfzpf2f5/3/

Comment: Its working and solve my problem, thanks